# how to auto scale images to fit into a slide in org mode export to beamer?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, images, beamer

When I insert an image into the slide it gets cropped to fit into the slide. 
**How do make an image to scale to fit in without cropping or padding?**

To include an image I use:

```
#+LaTeX:\includegraphics{curves.jpg}
```

org file header:

```
#+startup: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [bigger]
#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
```

and config file contains the following:

```
; allow for export=>beamer by placing

;; #+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer in org files
(unless (boundp 'org-export-latex-classes)
  (setq org-export-latex-classes nil))
(add-to-list 'org-export-latex-classes
  ;; beamer class, for presentations
  '("beamer"
     "\\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}\n
      \\mode<{{{beamermode}}}>\n
      \\usetheme{{{{beamertheme}}}}\n
      \\usecolortheme{{{{beamercolortheme}}}}\n
      \\beamertemplateballitem\n
      \\setbeameroption{show notes}
      \\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\n
      \\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\n
      \\usepackage{hyperref}\n
      \\usepackage{color}
      \\usepackage{listings}
      \\lstset{numbers=none,language=[ISO]C++,tabsize=4,
  frame=single,
  basicstyle=\\small,
  showspaces=false,showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  keywordstyle=\\color{blue}\\bfseries,
  commentstyle=\\color{red},
  }\n
      \\usepackage{verbatim}\n
      \\institute{{{{beamerinstitute}}}}\n          
       \\subject{{{{beamersubject}}}}\n"

     ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")

     ("\\begin{frame}[fragile]\\frametitle{%s}"
       "\\end{frame}"
       "\\begin{frame}[fragile]\\frametitle{%s}"
       "\\end{frame}")))

  ;; letter class, for formal letters

  (add-to-list 'org-export-latex-classes

  '("letter"
     "\\documentclass[11pt]{letter}\n
      \\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\n
      \\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\n
      \\usepackage{color}"

     ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
     ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
     ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
     ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
     ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after countless hours of research here is the solution. 
includegraphics accepts width parameter and by using textwidth variable we could set the
correct size.

```
#+LaTeX:\includegraphics[width = 1.06\textwidth]{curves.jpg}
```

Comment: Is it possible to set it for all images in a file?

Comment: @Rotkiv checkout the answer below, it might be a better option in your situation, just explicitly state attribute for each image you include. You could prob do an expansion on export if line contains .jpg insert the attribute above

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 1.06\textwidth
[[file:curves.jpg]]
```

This is described here: https://orgmode.org/manual/Images-in-LaTeX-export.html

> For specifying image ‘:width’, ‘:height’, and other ‘:options’, use this
> syntax:
>
> ```
> #+ATTR_LATEX: :width 5cm :options angle=90
> [[./img/sed-hr4049.pdf]]
> ```

Comment: Can you add a relevant quote from the documentation? Links might break over time, and it's expected to add a relevant quote to your answer.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the first snippet. `10.6` times the text width is almost guaranteed to make the image not fit into the slide. Is it maybe `1.06`?

Comment: Have you seen the size of my slides? :-)  Seriously, though, you are right of course.  In fact, the factor is in general probably going to be less that one.